# Extract and substitute substring between placeholders in string

Tags: python, regex

I have an input text,

```
input = 'I like {sushi} and {tempura}.'
```

and want to get a list and a replaced src from that.

```
lst = ['sushi', 'tempura']
src = 'I like * and *.'
```

I can use any tokens in the input/output strings instead of `{}` and `*`, such as `[]` or something.

Comment: Yes, lst = ['sushi', 'tempura'] is more accurate.
Sorry, its my mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import re
input = 'I like {sushi} and {tempura}.'
regex = re.compile(r'\{([^\}]*)\}')
lst = regex.findall(input)            #['sushi','tempura']
mod_str = regex.sub('*',input)        #I like * and *.
print (lst)
print (mod_str)
```

You can also do the replacement with string formatting:

```
mod_str = input.format(**dict((x,'*') for x in lst))
```

---

regex breakdown (note I used a raw string [`r'...'`]):

- `\{`  -- Look for literal '{'
- `[^\}]` -- match anything that isn't a literal '}'
- `*` -- match it as many times as possible.
- `\}` -- match a literal '}'

Parenthesis added to make a grouping in the match for `re.findall`.

---

As pointed out by DSM, another common idiom for finding the text between tokens is:

```
r"\{(.*?)\}"
```

which means:

- `\{` -- match literal '{'
- `(.*?)` -- match anything, but don't be greedy about it -- (don't eat stuff that the re will be able to use for the next portion of the match)
- `'\}'` -- match literal '}'

Comment: Thank you for your answer in detail. I've tried and got exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @koichi_n -- I'm happy to help.  There are people around here who are much better with regex than me -- I wouldn't be surprised if there's a cleaner way to do this, but it seems to work well enough :)

Comment: @DSM -- Yeah.  That's the other common idiom I've seen for matching one token until another.

Comment: @DSM -- I added your regex to my answer with an explanation (and citation).  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Because I can't stop myself from trying to find non-regex ways to do things, here's an approach which uses the standard string formatting:

```
>>> import string
>>> s = 'I like {sushi} and {tempura}.'
>>> parsed = string.Formatter().parse(s)
>>> fields = [p[1] for p in parsed if p[1]]
>>> src = s.format(**{f: '*' for f in fields})
>>> fields
['sushi', 'tempura']
>>> src
'I like * and *.'
```

Comment: +1.  I figured out how to do the second part without regex, but I couldn't get the first part.  Nicely done.

Answer (score 0):

An easy to understand method that matches text between `{}`

```
import re

input = 'I like {sushi} and {tempura}'
lst = re.findall('{[(a-zA-Z)]*}',input)
src = re.sub('{[a-zA-Z]*}','*',input)

print lst
['sushi', 'tempura']

print src
I like * and *
```

If you want to matching anything between `{}` then you would need to use `'{[^}]*}'` as mgilsons answer shows or `{(.*?)}` from DSM.