# Pig Latin- keep non-letters python

Tags: python, regex, non-alphanumeric

I am currently writing a pig Latin code and it requires all the non-letters to be ignored ie left in the same place of the word. For instance, Tom's would be om'sTay. So I deleted all non-alphabetic characters using:
    `word = re.sub('[^A-Za-z]', '', word)`
did the pig latin code and I want to bring the non-letters back.
Not sure how to bring back the non-letters to the same place of the changed word.

Comment: ... Don't delete them? Keep a backup? What's your exact question?

Comment: That sounds interesting. Did you have a question?

Comment: [Probably this can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315922/extract-and-substitute-substring-between-placeholders-in-string)?

Comment: I still can't understand what you're asking. Can you clarify? And does the question linked above help you?

Comment: Then you can use `re.findall` function, as described in the linked question above.

Comment: @user202729 Sorry the link didn't help because I do not want to replace the non-characters

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce  it is not a requirement. The only requirement is that the non-letters are not affected by piglatin ie: !apple becomes !applehay

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Yup input: the ap!ple is green output: ethay ap!plehay ishay eengray   or input: Kate's care output: ate'sKay arecay thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In[2]: def pig_latinize(word):
  ...:     cluster_dex = 0
  ...:     vowels = set('AEIOUaeiou')
  ...:     for i, char in enumerate(word, start=1):
  ...:         if not char.isalpha() or char in vowels:
  ...:             break
  ...:         cluster_dex = i
  ...:     if cluster_dex == 0:
  ...:         suffix = 'hay'
  ...:     elif cluster_dex == len(word):
  ...:         cluster_dex = 1
  ...:         suffix = 'way'
  ...:     else:
  ...:         suffix = 'ay'
  ...:     return '{}{}{}'.format(word[cluster_dex:], word[:cluster_dex], suffix)
  ...: 
  ...: 
  ...: def pig_latin(words):
  ...:     return ' '.join(pig_latinize(word) for word in words.split())
  ...: 
In[3]: pig_latin("Tom's") == "om'sTay"
Out[3]: True
In[4]: pig_latin('the ap!ple is green') == 'ethay ap!plehay ishay eengray'
Out[4]: True
In[5]: pig_latin("Kate's care") == "ate'sKay arecay"
Out[5]: True
In[6]: pig_latin('myth') == 'ythmway'
Out[6]: True
In[7]: pig_latin('cry') == 'rycway'
Out[7]: True
```

EDIT:

This shows a possible way of turning these functions into the class from the description you gave

```
>>> class PigLatin(object):
...     VOWELS = set('AEIOUaeiou')
...
...     def __init__(self, to_convert):
...         self.convert_words(to_convert)
...
...     def convert_words(self, to_convert):
...         if not isinstance(to_convert, list):
...             # if to_convert is a string, split into separate words
...             to_convert = to_convert.split()
...         self.pig_latin = ' '.join(
...             self.p_latin_converter(word) for word in to_convert)
...
...     def p_latin_converter(self, word):
...         cluster_dex = 0
...         for i, char in enumerate(word, start=1):
...             if not char.isalpha() or char in self.VOWELS:
...                 break
...             cluster_dex = i
...         if cluster_dex == 0:
...             suffix = 'hay'
...         elif cluster_dex == len(word):
...             cluster_dex = 1
...             suffix = 'way'
...         else:
...             suffix = 'ay'
...         return '{}{}{}'.format(word[cluster_dex:], word[:cluster_dex], suffix)
...

# *** An object of this method initializes the string it wants to 
# convert when it is created. ***
>>> p = PigLatin("Tom's")  # initialize with a sting
# pig_latin attribute is then set with the converted text
>>> p.pig_latin == "om'sTay"
True

# *** Further, the class should have a method that allows the string to be
# modified to perform another conversion. ***
>>> p.convert_words('the ap!ple is green')  # modify the pig_latin attribute
>>> p.pig_latin == 'ethay ap!plehay ishay eengray'
True

# *** build a pigLatin_class that works with strings and lists and has a
# method to convert a string into pig latin. ***
>>> p.convert_words(['myth', 'cry'])  # use a list of strings
>>> p.pig_latin == 'ythmway rycway'
True

# *** The set of VOWELS can be defined as a static attribute of the class. ***
>>> p.VOWELS
{'E', 'e', 'A', 'O', 'a', 'i', 'u', 'I', 'U', 'o'}

# *** The class pigLatin should be based on the basic object datatype. ***
>>> isinstance(p, object)  # inherits from object "class PigLatin(object):"
True

# *** method pLatin_converter can be used. ***
>>> p.pig_latin  # current pig_latin attribute
'ythmway rycway'
# returns a word without modifying the pig_latin attribute
>>> p.p_latin_converter("Kate's care")
"ate's careKay"
# show that the pig_latin attribute wasn't modified after the above call
>>> p.pig_latin
'ythmway rycway'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! however the input:cry should output:rycway

Comment: yes for a word without a vowel and the last letter goes to the end and the suffix way is added input: myth output:ythmway

Comment: can you please explain what '{}{}{}' means

Comment: Thanks you! I have to change the pig latin to a class and since there are two definitions I am struggling to understand which variables to add self. to .

Comment: Thanks! we have to build a class that will convert a string into pig latin and it should be based on the basic object datatype. The class should have a method that allows the string to be modified to perform another conversion.

Comment: "build a pigLatin_class that works with strings and lists and has a method to convert a string into pig latin. method pLatin_converter can be used. The class pigLatin should be based on the basic object datatype. An object of this method initializes the string it wants to convert when it is created. Further, the class should have a method that allows the string to be modified to perform another conversion. The set of VOWELS can be defined as a static attribute of the class." Those are the only instructions given - Sorry - advice on how to proceed would be great. Thanks a lot

Comment: Great! but when I input:                                                                            p = PigLatin
p.p_latin_converter("Kate's car")  to convert the word I in return get an error :  p_latin_converter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'word'

Comment: Thanks! for the original pig Latin it worked correctly where Kate's care would be "ate'sKay arecay" but for some reason, the output here is "ate's careKay" sorry for the trouble

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway :)